# How to change the maximum URL length permitted on Microsoft Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, request.querystring, azure-application-gateway

URL querystrings for complex REST queries are failing for an application behind the Azure Application Gateway. When run locally a long URL > 2048 characters is passed on fine indicating the issue is not with Apache.  When coming via the gateway to the same query the 404 response is returned.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation or API/UI option with Azure describing how or permitting this limit to be increased.

We have tested this also with a backend of IIS set to a long limit.  Again on localhost the URL is passed fine, but from outside coming via the gateway the 404 response is returned. Shorter length querystrings pass through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I checked with Microsoft support and currently (At the time of this writing) there is no option to increase the url length limit. There is a hard limit on the application gateway where the maximum amount of characters accepted is 2048. I will be asking for this feature in their feedback site.